# valgrind no such file or directory

Tags: apt-get

I just installed valgrind from `apt-get` and it is installed to `/usr/bin/valgrind` according to `which`.  However...

```
$ valgrind
bash: /usr/local/bin/valgrind: No such file or directory
```

What is happening here?

```
$ /usr/bin/valgrind 
valgrind: no program specified
valgrind: Use --help for more information.
```

Also... valgrind won't run when a  file is provided...

```
$ /usr/bin/valgrind ex3
valgrind: ex3: command not found
```

EDIT:
I have no aliases applicable to valgrind.  The file in `/usr/bin/valgrind` is not a symbolic link.

However, running `/usr/bin/valgrind ./ex3` does run correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem with yours but reversed ! Mine actual valgrind is at `/usr/local/bin/valgrind`, and my shell keeps complaining `-bash: /usr/bin/valgrind: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check if you have any aliases in your shell that is redirecting valgrind to the `/usr/local/bin` In bash, you do this by typing `alias` (or `alias | grep valgrind` if you want to get fancy -- if it returns nothing, there is no alias).

Second, the path to your program to run has to be resolvable. Unless `ex3` is on your `$PATH`, you would need to do either:

```
 $ /usr/bin/valgrind ./ex3
```

if you are in the same directory as `ex3` or

```
 $ /usr/bin/valgrind /path/to/ex3
```

from anywhere on the file-system.